# Rails: How to raise an error in a before_update method to the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have searched a lot for this issue with no luck...

I have a model with a before_update method, I can't replace it with a validator because the actual method checks the existance of many things and update many others. My question is, How can I raise an error if a process from the before_update method fails? Something like:

```
def update_status
    if !(many verifications and updates)
       self.errors[:base] << "Could not update if ...."
    end
end
```

With the abobe code I get the update notice from the controller after the page loads, but I want to show the error from the before_update method. How can I show the error to the user?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def update_status
    if !(many verifications and updates)
       raise "Could not update if ...."
    end
end
```

Now do show the error message on the controller you could do something like this:

```
begin
  @myObject.update_status
rescue => ex
  flash[:notice] = ex.message
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe! I tried this before and it give me the error but not as a notice or error that I can show in the user interface. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: You want to show the exception message to the user of the site?